# ggplot: How do I select data above a certain threshold but still display the correct percentage

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage, x-axis

I would like to plot ordinal data and display the percentage of each ordinal value on the y axis. However, I only want to plot data above a certain threshold. So I have a df with the variable "Liking of cats" which is on a 1-5 Likert scale, and I only want to plot the proportion of values 4-5.

I also want to make subplots with some categorical data, such as gender and whether the participants own a car.

Happy for help!

Comment: Hi could you put some data (even fake or test data) so we can provide some code to you?

Comment: Can you provide some code with previous attempts and some sample data that works with that code? As your post stands, you're asking us to solve a problem that is only tangible to you.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example, but likely you can plot this by calculating the percents in one column, then making a new column for plotting that filters the values you don't want to display.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.